# Symfony2.x to 3.x Forms

Tags: forms, symfony

In Symfony 2.x, I used this way to display form with custom fields

ProductType form class

```
public function __construct(array $aCustomFieldsList)
{
    $this->aCustomFields = $aCustomFieldsList;
}

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [ "label" => "Name" ])
        ->add('price', MoneyType::class, [ "label" => "Price" ]);


    foreach( $this->aCustomFields as $n=>$sCustomField )
    {
        $builder->add($sCustomField, TextType::class, [ "label" => {$sCustomField}"]);
    }

    $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, [ "label" => "Save" ]);
}
```

And in the controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ProductType($aCustomFields), $product);
```

But in Symfony 3.x, the first argument of the method createForm() don't expect instanciated object anymore, but a string representing the class name with namespace, like this :

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
```

What is the way to do the same as I did with Symfony 3.x ?

Comment: Pass your custom fields via the options parameter.  And yes, migrating from Forms 2 to Forms 3 can be a pain.  You will probably run into more issues as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cerad suggests you can pass those options in using the options field. This was recommended even back in 2.x. You then define the option requirements for it. If you make the field required like i have then you will get errors if its not provided when you build the form.

```
// Form Type
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, [ "label" => "Name" ])
        ->add('price', MoneyType::class, [ "label" => "Price" ]);


    foreach( $options['custom_field_list'] as $n=>$sCustomField )
    {
        $builder->add($sCustomField, TextType::class, [ "label" => {$sCustomField}]);
    }

    $builder->add('save', SubmitType::class, [ "label" => "Save" ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'custom_field_list' => [],
    ]);
    $resolver->setRequired([
        'custom_field_list' => true
    ]);
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes([
        'custom_field_list'=>'array'
    ]);
}
```

Then call it in the controller:

```
//controller

$form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product, [
    'custom_field_list' => $aCustomFields
]);
```